# tools to test a web site for XSS, sql inyection and other vulnerabilities

Tags: security, sql-injection, xss

I'd like to know if there's any automated testing tool to check for vulnerabilities

I've seen a couple of reports, and they all seem to be done but automated tools...

Answer (score 2):

The best, highest quality, and most accurate testing will always be done by a skilled penetration tester. This can be very expensive though.

As far as automated tools, tons of options exist.

Commercial Grade tools (run anywhere from $300-$25,000 for a copy):
- Veracode Dynamic Scanner
- Whitehat
- HP WebInspect
- Cenzic Hailstorm
- IBM AppScan
- NTOSpider
- Qualys
- Burp Professional

Free/Open Source:
- w3af
- OWASP ZAP
- Acunetix has a free trial for their commerical product http://www.acunetix.com/cross-site-scripting/scanner/
- Skipfish
- Wfuzz

All of these tools will require some basic knowledge of web application vulnerabilities, as well as some manual configuration in order to get legitimate results.

I

Answer (score 0):

looking for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965/checklist-for-web-site-programming-vulnerabilities) at SO, I've found this site that lists several tools

http://labs.securitycompass.com/exploit-me/

http://www.dwheeler.com/flawfinder/#othertools